# How to check that a regular expression fall into infty loop or not?

Tags: c++, regex

I'm trying to learn and hopefully use regular expression with Qt.

I found that some patterns cause handler to fall into loop. for example searching `\b\b` in a text, never will terminate. and number of these expressions is infinite (`\b\b\b`,`\b\b\b\b` and so on). 
I'd like to determine and control all invalid expressions.

Is there an algorithm to distinguish valid and invalid expressions? If not, how can I prevent my program from falling into an infinite loop?

Comment: Are your regular expression patterns being constructed from user input or something? Why do you need to programmatically check this?

Comment: yes. they are constructed from user input.

Comment: Is this in C++? (based on the qt tag)

Comment: @marcog: yes, but does it matter? as far as I know regular expressions are language-independent?

Comment: @Sorush Rabiee: *as far as I know regular expressions are language-independent?* - They are *not* language-independent.

Comment: @Sorush They are to some degree, but there are some very different syntaxes. The reason I ask though is that limiting the runtime is far more language-dependant.

Comment: @Mark Byers: so, regular expression syntax that used in c++ is different from that one used in python?

Comment: @Sorush Rabiee: C++ doesn't have a standard regular expression syntax, AFAIK. Boost have their own variation for example.

Answer (score 4):

Regular expressions shouldn't go into an infinite loop, but they can take a long time to evaluate.

I'd suggest using an API with a time out / step limit. If you don't have access to such an API then run the code in a separate thread or process and kill it if it doesn't respond in a timely fashion.

It sounds like there is a bug in the regular expression engine you are using if searching for `\b\b` causes an infinite loop.

Comment: I think there is no bug. I tried kiki (written with python and using another implementation) and another testing tool and got same result... so there should be something wrong with \b\b or there is same bug in many implementations...

Comment: @Sorush Rabiee: Could be bugs in multiple implementations. The default regex module `re` works fine: `import re; print re.match(r'\b\b', 'abc def')`

Comment: @Sorush: It's quite possible that Python and Qt are both using the PCRE library under the hood. If that's the case, they'll have the *same* bugs in the implementation.

Comment: Before we start hunting bugs, I'd like to see an example of this behavior.  @Sorush, please post some code we can run ourselves, ideally at an online testing site like http://ideone.com/

Answer (score 0):

You can use any of the online Regular Expression Testing Tools like [this one](http://www.spaweditor.com/scripts/regex/).
Or download something like this and customize: [RegEx Builder (open source)](http://sourceforge.net/projects/regexbuilder/)

Comment: Ok, this is not a real answer. I like to learn how can I programmatically check an expression.

Comment: @Sorush: See what RegEx engine Qt is using. Then obtain an open source RegEx checker/tester and customize it. It will take a while for you to implement a RegEx checker from scratch.